# NPM Install - ignore errors

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to do `npm install` to download all the packages listed in my package.json, but one of the packages doesn't work because some node-gyp bs, but it doesn't just skip that package, it fails to install any.

How can i make it ignore the errors and just continue installing packages? I don't need all of them for all parts of my program.

Comment: I don't think you can ignore a package that is used in a nested dependency, if is the case.

Comment: What is the error with `node-gyp`?

Comment: node-gyp is angry because it cant find the proper VS build tools. I've already wasted too much time (and disk space) trying to get it to work, so I gave up. Not all parts of my app use every package, so I'd still like to install the rest anyway.

 It's not a nested dependency, its one of mine, but i still need it to be in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is temporarily remove the packages that require node-gyp, and then install the packages and add them back to your package.json. Basically, you'd be removing the packages that are being troublemakers, and then putting them back so that you can remember what they are.

Comment: this was what i ended up having to do